What is the origin of the phrase “aiding and abetting”?
In American law regarding crimes (e.g. theft, murder, etc…), there is a locution: to aid and abet.
Merriam-Webster, offers no elucidation for the compound phrase, it limits itself to saying:

aiding and abetting idiom
(formal) helping and encouraging

Historically,  it seems that abet (ibid) is related to bait

"to harass (a bear with dogs), bait," borrowed from Old Low Franconian *bētan; akin to Old English bǣtan "to set upon (with animals), bait"

Which suggests that abet originally meant to lure an animal to  bite, and was later used as a metaphor for enticing someone to commit a deed.

What is the history of the binomial phrase aiding and abetting?

Have you done any of your own research  to find the answer for yourself, like checking a dictionary? Merriam-Webster for instance?

Where do you find instances of these phrases "aid and bait", etc? Because when I Googled "aid and bait", it seemed very rare and I found nothing to suggest it was a common locution or meant the same as "aid and abet".

I can't find any references to a verb intercategorial polyseme of 'abed', which 'aid' would surely require in an irreversible binomial (such as 'aid and abet'). This indicates strongly that either catachresis or word play (as must be the case with 'aid and provide a bed')  is in play. More research (than that Mari-Lou has provided) is necessary, but the answer is probably that 'aid' and 'abet'  are historically connected, but that the 'bed' link  is modern punning.

@EdwinAshworth - in my school at the age of 11, our classroom had desks in pairs. To prevent cheating in the termly tests, half of us in each class swapped with boys one year older so that each 11 year old was paired with a 12 year old (different papers, of course.) The older boy who sat next to me chuckled and drew my attention to a question in his geometry paper, about 'the quadrilateral ABED'. He thought this was a hoot. It was 1963.

... It must have been a four-poster.

*From Middle English abetten, abette, from Old French abeter (“to entice”), from a- (“to”) + beter (“hound on, urge, to bait”), either from Middle Dutch bētan (“incite”) or from Old Norse beita (“to cause to bite, bait, incite”), from Proto-Germanic baitijaną (“to cause to bite”), from Proto-Indo-European bʰeyd- (“to ...

@EdwinAshworth  According to the notice, the question is closed because the author should have consulted a dictionary. Merriam-Webster is a dictionary. I included it in the edit. We had one user (KillingTime) who cast their vote to reopen after the edit, and then minutes later, cast their vote to close it. Bonkers. This site is completely bonkers maintaining an unsupportable unreasonable unhelpful  illogical level of standard. Aiding and abetting what's the history of that phrase? Do you find that in M-W?

If the OP, Toothpick anemone would like the question to be reopened, they either have to find instances where  “aid and abed”, “aid and provide a bed” –which nearly everyone would dispute having the same meaning as aid and abet – and "aid and bait" were used in writing OR eliminate that section completely because it lacks evidence (I didn't bother searching, because I've never come across any of these eggcorns/ malapoprisms).

@ I repeat, I can't find any references to a verb intercategorial polyseme of 'abed', which 'aid' would surely require in an irreversible binomial (such as 'aid and abet'). This research could be expected on a site aimed at linguists and other mature Anglophones. Stuart also carried out research that could have been expected, and commented '... when I Googled "aid and bait", it seemed very rare and I found nothing to suggest it was a common locution or meant the same as "aid and abet" '.  The usages are almost certainly non-standard and tongue-in-cheek, not suitable  for ELU.

Unfortunately, I cannot vote to reopen a question twice. I believe this question has a lot going for it, it should never have been closed in the first place.

With regard to the new question: Phrase Finder has an explanation; once, it was among the common/standard references expected to be consulted before submitting  a request about the origin of a phrase. I am told I can't vote to close again after retracting my vote; this is misrepresentation.

First the post was closed because it lacked research, then a dictionary citation was included, a surprisingly impoverished one, now an answer can be find at Phrase Finder. Is there no room for improvement?  I'm sure more could be said and added, but fev has done a good job so far.  Besides not every native speaker or user on Stack Exchange knows the existence of Phrase Finder or etymonline.

I hadn't seen this question when I posted my answer to the related question "Is there really any positive use of 'abet'? If so, when and how did it develop?" but that answer devotes some attention to early occurrences of "aid and abet" as well as to its formal definition in Black's Law Dictionary in the sphere of criminal law.

Aid is easy to understand. Abet, according to etymonline comes from French:

late 14c., "urge on, incite" (implied in abetting), from Old French abeter "to bait, to harass with dogs," literally "to cause to bite".

In the expression we commonly use today in law, this meaning was lost.
Gary Martin, Writer and researcher on the origins of phrases and the creator of the Phrase Finder website explains:

The phrase ‘aid and abet’ was coined in the late 18th century, by which time the term ‘abet’ had lost its original ’cause to bite’ meaning. An early example of its use dates from 1798, when George Washington included it in a letter, first published in Writings, 1893. He didn’t appear to have any better opinion of the French than that of the US administration concerning the Gallic reluctance to aid and abet the war in Iraq:

My mind is not a little agitated by the outrageous conduct of France towards the United States, and at the inimitable conduct of its partisans, who aid and abet their measures.


The Dictionary of Clichés by Christine Ammer (2013), quoted by FreeDictionary adds that

The pairing of these nearly synonymous verbs, always in this order, comes from criminal law, where it denotes helping, facilitating and promoting the commission of a crime. Although the term still is principally used in relation to criminal actions, it gradually crept into more general speech, as in

The influx of Canada geese on the golf course, aided and abetted by people feeding them .



We find the formulaic "abet him and aid him" in records of the House of Lords from 1642, and "aid, assist, and abet" from the House of Commons in 1647.

1641 abbet , procure , counsell , aid , or comfort such , is treason The Complete Justice Note the double b in "abbet" A year later the new edition corrected it to abet

This citation proves the phrase, in mid-17th century, was originally longer.
